# How to enforce tls version to TLSv using `sqlalchemy.create_engine` to connect an AWS RDS MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am using the following code to connect to my AWS RDS MySQL database:

```
mysql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://xxx:xxx@xxx:xxx')
```

Now I want to enforce it to use `TLSv1.2`, how can I achieve this? I've read a couple of documentations online but couldn't found anything. Thanks.

Comment: enforce it on server side

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to enforce it from the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[SqlAlchemy\]\[mssql\]\[tls1.2\] How to enforce TLS 1.2 for SqlAlchemy connecting to MS SQL Server using pyodbc from windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170526/sqlalchemymssqltls1-2-how-to-enforce-tls-1-2-for-sqlalchemy-connecting-to)